# How does Angular2's pipes work with data binding?

Tags: angular

I'm writing a simple todo app to learn Angular 2. I noticed that using pipes break the update behavior.

I have the following template

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" #queryBox (keyup)="query=queryBox.value">

<ul class="task-list">
    <task-item *ng-for="#task of tasks | filter:containsString:query" [task]="task" (onDelete)="delete($event)"></task-item>
</ul>
```

and when I click on the delete button, the underlying data model is changed but this change is not reflected in the UI. I have determined it's because the filter pipe doesn't get called. If I change the above line to

```
<task-item *ng-for="#task of tasks" [task]="task" (onDelete)="delete($event)"></task-item>
```

then things like add, delete works again, but obvious I don't get filtering. Why would adding pipes break the update behavior of this binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because by default Pipes are stateless <strike>(they render UI just once)</strike>.

You have to add :

```
 @Pipe({
  selector: ...,
  pure: false
})
```

When you set 'pure' to false, Angular updates the data inside the pipe each cycle.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I thought Angular 2 is reactive, aren't pipes conceptually functions? My pipe has no internal state. There are 2 parameters, a predicate : (value:any, query:string) => boolean, and query: string. When either is updated, the pipe should re-evaluate.

Comment: No, it's not the default behaviour, if you want your pipe to updates data when there's a change, you have to add 'pure: false' in the @Pipe decorator. I think that the Angular team do things that way to save memory and speeds up applications.

Comment: Although by default Pipes are stateless, they _can_ re-render the UI more than once.  E.g., look at the Power Boost Calculator in the [pipes dev guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html).  The reason the UI doesn't re-render for the OP is because the delete operation (I assume a `splice()`) doesn't alter the `tasks` reference, so the pipe doesn't see any change to its input.

Comment: You don't need to use `pure: false` for the pipe to re-evaluate and update the UI. See @MarkRajcok answer for the correct usage. Adding `pure: false` can lead to performance issues, don't use this unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

By default, pipes are stateless/pure. If their inputs don't change, the pipes are not executed during a change detection cycle. For this question, where we have

```
"#task of tasks | filter:containsString:query"
```

`tasks`, `containsString` and `query` are the inputs, and pipe `filter` is stateless/pure. 
`tasks` is an array (reference).

When a task is deleted, the array *reference* doesn't change – the `tasks` input to the pipe doesn't change – hence the stateless/pure pipe is not executed.

If we make the pipe stateful with `pure: false`, then the pipe will be evaluated on every change detection cycle – even if the inputs do not change.

You may also need to either

- specify the `onPush` change detection strategy for the component (if possible), or
- implement the pipe's `transform()` method such that it returns the same array (reference).

These alternatives are explained in detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34497504/215945) (I don't want to repeat all of that here).