# EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked ion-input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i'm trying to create an edit , so i create a form and then i assign the value. But i get an error

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value:
>   'XXXXXX'.

Here is my edituser.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/Storage';

/**
 * Generated class for the EdituserPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-edituser',
  templateUrl: 'edituser.html',
})
export class EdituserPage {

    fullname : any;
    Deskripsi : any;
    phone:any;
    Email:any;
    user_id:any
  userData = {"username": "","password": "", "fullName": "","Email": "", "Deskripsi" : "", "Phone":""};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public storage: Storage) {

  }
ionViewDidLoad() {
      this.storage.get('userData').then((val) => {
               this.fullname = val.fullname;
               this.Deskripsi = val.Deskripsi;
               this.phone = val.phone;
               this.Email = val.Email;
               this.user_id = val.user_id;
        });
  }

  update(){
        console.log(this.userData);
  }


}
```

and here is my form edituser.html

```
<ion-list margin-top>
    <ion-item>        
            <ion-label> <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon></ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="userData.fullname" value="{{fullname}}" type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

     <ion-item>        
            <ion-label> <ion-icon name="md-phone-portrait"></ion-icon></ion-label>
            <ion-input  [(ngModel)]="userData.phone" value="{{phone}}"  type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>        
            <ion-label> <ion-icon name="md-mail"></ion-icon></ion-label>
            <ion-input  [(ngModel)]="userData.Email" value="{{Email}}"  type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>        
            <ion-label> <ion-icon name="md-megaphone"></ion-icon></ion-label>
            <ion-textarea  [(ngModel)]="userData.Deskripsi" value="{{Deskripsi}}"  type="text"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>        
        <button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="update();" float-right>Update</button>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Expression has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283293/angular-2-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error due to angular lifecycle. Run your project with `enableProdMode` as below.

In your app.module.ts (main component where you define project bootstrapping and other component registration)

```
import { Component, NgModule, enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";

export class AppModule {

}
enableProdMode();
```

Comment: Isn't `enableProdMode();` just not outputting the errors? I don't think that this is a viable fix, the error will still happen but it's just not printing it to the console due to the enabled production mode.

Comment: As @moritzg said, it's not a fix nor a workaround. It's just hiding the printed error.

Answer (score 1):

`ionViewDidLoad` doesn't seem like the right hook. This sounds like the view is already done loading, which means all the bindings have set. After that you change the bindings, which probably causes this issue.

You should move your `storage.get` to the `ngOnInit` life-cycle hook

Answer (score 1):

This is a **lifecycle error**. Angular tells you that during its lifecycle check, you changed a variable, and it got lost.

To avoid that, you can wrap the content of your `ionViewDidLoad()` into a timeout, or call it somewhere else. By the way, where do you call it  ?