# Is it OK to run Angular in developer mode on live web app?

Tags: angular

I have a web app that uses Angular on the front end. During code review the reviewer noticed that my live app is running Angular in development mode. He said that there are errors in live mode that wouldn't allow it to compile or something. I talked to my dev and he said that production mode doesn't handle dialogs very well so we need to run it in developer mode for it to work. Is there a solution to make dialogs work properly in production mode or should we keep running it in developer mode? Are there any drawbacks to running it in developer mode?

Comment: application in dev mode is at leats 10 times bigger. Be careful about your ux

Comment: I think you reviewer's comment about "errors in live mode" are bs... Let us try to address your production build issues...
What happens when you run `ng build --prod`? Please add the reported issues to the question

Comment: I can only agree with @TheFabio - "doesn't handle dialogs very well" is a really broad answer. If possible, you want your Angular apps to run in production mode and AoT compiled. However, this question was actually answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868810/what-is-the-difference-between-production-and-development-mode-in-angular2

If that's OK for you, is up to you.

Comment: another major issue with deploying your app in dev mode is that the generated names of the files in dev mode are constant, "app.js" , "vendor.js" and so own. Because web browsers cache files by name, every time your app is updated users could be stuck in previous versions until their browser cache is cleaned...

Comment: Thanks for the replies all. Asked reviewer for the build errors and will post those here when he replies.

Comment: Here is a list of warnings and some recommendations the code reviewer made. I'm just wondering how running in dev mode will affect performance and user experience. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sw6EUivqJ8obOSiDK3Tnesf_Y746wY4e/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Basically reviewer said that the main issue was with "ngx-bootstrap”. The version of the package used wasn’t compatible to be run on production that's why angular prod build was failing.

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: No

A good explanation on the difference beween the prod and dev mode builds is given on the answers to this question:
[What is the difference between production and development mode in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868810/what-is-the-difference-between-production-and-development-mode-in-angular2)

A more in-depth answer can be found on [this blog](https://medium.com/@kavisha.talsania/angular-development-vs-production-build-671b7fd5dbf4).

Main dot points in regards to deploying angular apps with dev built:

- Source Map(.map files) would be available to all users
- no Minification and Uglification
- Css in js files  (in prod mode css is built in css files)
- no Tree Shaking (considerably bigger files)
- JIT compiler (considerable slower app)