# how to add filter in angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

could you please tell me how to add filter in angular2.Actually whenever user type anything in input field it should filter the list as in autocomplete  ..can we do in angular 2 ?

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/hfhY6EdLVNOLP6d4QsWP?p=preview

```
<div>
  <input type='text' #inputD>
     <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#elt of elements | async">{{elt.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

update here is my filter

http://plnkr.co/edit/hfhY6EdLVNOLP6d4QsWP?p=preview

```
import {Injectable, Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
@Injectable()
export class Listfilter {
  transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
    return items.filter(item => item.column === args[0]);
  }
}
```

how to add key up and key down event to fliter list in angular 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i show only results where card.column value matches column.id in angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736315/how-can-i-show-only-results-where-card-column-value-matches-column-id-in-angular)

Comment: wait I will try and update you

Comment: see this http://plnkr.co/edit/hfhY6EdLVNOLP6d4QsWP?p=preview still want to change

Comment: You don't need `@Injectable()` when there is already decorators like `@Component()`, `@Directive()`, `@Pipe()`.

Comment: ok I will try and update you

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the pipe to the annotation where you want to use it

```
@Component({

    templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
    providers: [SharedService],
    pipes: [Listfilter]
})
```

and use it like

```
<li *ngFor="#elt of elements | async | filter:arg1:arg2">{{elt.name}}</li>
```

Not tried myself yet though.

The pipe also shouldn't throw on `null`

```
export class Listfilter {
  transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
    if(!items) {
      return null;
    }
    return items.filter(item => item.name === args[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your plunker links. They don't contain any changes.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ienTN54PdS3bydfDgRGI?p=preview Instead of `'abc'` you probably want to link to a model variable that contains the value entered into the input.