# Angular2 Pipe filter by name best approach

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

Just wondering what is the best approach for using PIPE in Angular2 in my situation, although my solution has worked well.

Let's start it.
I have this json array https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

My PIPE

```
transform(value: any, name: any): any
{
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (name == null) {
        return value;
    }

    return value.filter(user => {
        return user.name.indexOf(name) != -1
    });
}
```

Firstly, I return null when value is null because I am fetching data from API according to this [Cannot read property 'filter' of null in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337076/cannot-read-property-filter-of-null-in-angular-2).

```
if (value == null) {
    return null;
}
```

Secondly, I return null because I want the original data first without filtering.

```
if (name == null) {
    return value;
}
```

Last, I filter the result inside the ngFor according to what the user has typed in the input.

```
user.name.indexOf(name) != -1
```

Input to filter data

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userSearch">
```

My ngFor

```
<div class="list-item" *ngFor="let user of (usersList | filterPipe:userSearch)">
    <div><strong>Name:</strong> {{ user.name }}</div>
    <div><strong>Username:</strong> {{ user.username }}</div>
    <div><strong>Email:</strong> {{ user.email }}</div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

So, what do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to return null when `value` is `undefined`:
In your pipe you can do following:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'search',
    pure: false
})
@Injectable()
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any[], name: any, caseInsensitive: boolean): any {
        if (name !== undefined) {
            // filter users, users which match and return true will be kept, false will be filtered out
            return users.filter((user) => {
                if (caseInsensitive) {
                    return (user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
                } else {
                    return (user.name.indexOf(name) !== -1);
                }
            });
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

as for your problem , when `value` is `undefined`, you can surround your `*ngFor` by a `div` which has `*ngIf` on value,so this will be rendered only when `userList` is not `undefined`.

```
<div *ngIf="usersList">
    <div class="list-item" *ngFor="let user of (usersList | search:userSearch:true)">  
        <!-- true is added for case insensitive search -->
        <div><strong>Name:</strong> {{ user.name }}</div>
        <div><strong>Username:</strong> {{ user.username }}</div>
        <div><strong>Email:</strong> {{ user.email }}</div>
    <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, it helped! I think you made a confusion between value and user. In the pipe it should return value once 'value' is the name of the argument. Apart from that, it worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: @TiagoMatos glad to hear that :) close the question by accepting the answer if your issue is resolved.