# Angular 2: text filter on input text change

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

**Angular2**, in my `component.ts`, I grab a list of Video Objects and store in `_videos:Video[]`

In my html, I display the videos,

```
<tr *ngFor="#video of _videos">
```

Now I want to create a search input field in the html to filter the videos. I am trying to use pipe:

```
import {Pipe,PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'textfilter'
})

export class TextFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
    if(args[1].toString().length === 0)
      return items;
    return items.filter(item => item[args[0]].indexOf(args[1]) !== -1);
  }
}
```

in `ts`,

```
private _videoTitleFilter: string ='';
```

in `html`,

```
  <tr>
    <th><input id="videoTitleFilter" placeholder="Filter">{{_videoTitleFilter}}</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="#video of _videos |textfilter:'title':_videoTitleFilter">
```

It seems the binding is not working. The pipe works for the first time. Is it right to use pipe here? Or I should create a new array `_videoList: Video[]`, listen to the keyup event with throttle to change the `_videoList` and use it in `*ngFor`, instead of `_videos` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your pipe not pure:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'textfilter',
  pure: false
})
export class TextFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
    if(args[1].toString().length === 0)
      return items;
    return items.filter(item => item[args[0]].indexOf(args[1]) !== -1);
  }
}
```

This question could help you:

- [NgFor doesn't update data with Pipe in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456430/ngfor-doesnt-update-data-with-pipe-in-angular2/)

Comment: Tks Thierry, changed, still no update. I will read through the post. Pls note there is no update on my _videos. It remains unchanged after the http fetch.

Comment: How do your input is bound to the `_videoTitleFilter` property?

Comment: My bad, I change to ngModel.  Tks