# List with ngFor not updated when using custom filter and subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've made a search component which has an input field which filters the search result list when typing. I also have a websocket that pushes new or changed values to the list like this:

```
this._fooService.foos.subscribe(foos => {
    this.foos = foos;
});
```

This works fine when I don't have the filter and list updates when I change the filter search term. In template it's simply:

```
<div *ngFor="let foo of foos | filterFoos: searchTerm">
```

I've tried doing this: [NgFor doesn't update data with Pipe in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456430/ngfor-doesnt-update-data-with-pipe-in-angular2)

But it hasn't worked. I have same kind of search component with bars in my other view and it works fine with the filter. Although there is a promise, which needs to complete before this.bars = bars is run.

---

EDIT:

_fooService.foos is Observable`<Foo[]>` and it is initialized in constructor:

```
this.foos = this._fooObservable.asObservable();
```

where _fooObservable is BehaviorSubject`<Foo[]>` and new Foos are added to it with .next method (along with the old Foos).

The filter pipe is like this:

```
@Pipe({name: 'filterFoos'})
export class FilterFoosPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform = (foos: Foo[], searchTerm: string = ""): any => {
    let filtered = foos.filter((foo) => {
        return foo.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    });
    return filtered;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add a plunker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a stream, you could use the [`async`-pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html):

```
<div *ngFor="let foo of _fooService.foos | async | filterFoos: searchTerm">
```

That way you can even remove your custom subscription in your controller, which is prone to memory-leaks anyways. The async-pipe should automatically trigger an update in the UI.

---

A second thing to watch out for is the ngZone - in some rare cases, some store-update is triggered outside the ngZone and therefore not triggering a change-detection-cycle, this can be fixed by explicitly wrapping the update in an [ngZone.run](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html):

```
ngZone.run(() => doMyStoreUpdate(...));
```

Comment: The async pipe seems very elegant solution but it still doesn't update the UI :(

I tried ngZone before and that didn't help either.

Comment: And you are sure that the observable emits data? Did you add some logs to the streams yet?

Comment: At least the custom subscription in my controller received modified data (I removed it after adding async). I edited the question for more information about observable.

Comment: Can you also post your filter method? Does it work with async and without the filter maybe?

Comment: I added the filter pipe to the question. It seems to work with async and without filtering but when I add filter, no updates to UI.

Comment: Not sure if that is the issue but worth a try: can you change the transform from being a member variable that holds an anonymous function to a member method?

Comment: It didn't help :(

Comment: If it works without the filter - then i'd say the best way is to set breakpoints in your filter and check it there

Comment: It doesn't reach the filter's transform function, only after I alter the searchTerm input

Comment: Hm, it's currently very hard to tell without having the complete picture, could you maybe add a plunkr?

Comment: Hmm, I did a conversion to all the Foos to simplify them as FooSearchResult in a method that returns a Promise with FooSearchResults and using .then, it works fine.