# Unwanted event trigger on mouseover Angular HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the below partial `HTML` in my Material Table Angular application.

//HTML

```
 <button mat-icon-button class="mat-18" (click)="updateStatus(element.id)" 
            [disabled]="validateToWork(element.reachedTime)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
         </button>
```

//Typescript

```
  validateToWork(reachedTime:any):boolean{

    if(reachedTime&& new Date(this.datePipe.transform(reachedTime, DATE_WITH_TIME)) < new Date())
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
```

The above code works fine and the `edit` button is disabled. But what i observed is when i have a `console.log(reachedTime)` in the typescript like,

```
console.log(reachedTime)
if(reachedTime&& new Date(this.datePipe.transform(reachedTime, DATE_WITH_TIME)) < new Date())
```

I could see the `event` is triggered on every `mouseover` i do on the table. Its weird for me and not sure. How can i stop that?

Below is the `console log` i have

[image: Log found in the browser]

Any help ?

Comment: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Answer (score 2):

### Why

One of the rule with angular, is that you should try to **avoid using method inside the html**.

doing so

```html
<button mat-icon-button class="mat-18" (click)="updateStatus(element.id)" 
  [disabled]="validateToWork(element.reachedTime)">
  <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Will force `[disabled]` to be recalculated each time you make **any** interaction with the page, mouseover being one.

To test this out, just scroll or click somewhere, you should have the same result.

---

### How to fix it

Add the logic inside a pipe

```js
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'
import { DATE_WITH_TIME } from 'from/some/where'

@Pipe({
  name: 'validateToWork',
})
export class ValidateToWorkPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  transform(reachedTime: any): boolean {
    // <- do add a definition, try to never use any
    if (reachedTime && new Date(this.datePipe.transform(reachedTime, DATE_WITH_TIME)) < new Date())
      return true
    else return false
  }
}
```

And use it in your code like follow

```html
<button mat-icon-button class="mat-18" (click)="updateStatus(element.id)" 
  [disabled]="element.reachedTime | validateToWork">
  <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

#### Further more

- Do not forget to declare it in your module under the `declarations: []` or in the `imports: []` if you did create a module for that specific pipe
- If you declares it directly, you won't be able to use it somewhere else.
- If this is an object, you will have to [manually trigger the update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43799886/11135174)