# Angular 4 ngFor pipe not re filter after add an element

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-pipe

I need to use data and sort them by price first the pipe works fine but when I add new element it add it in the last line and not sort them again

```
<tr *ngFor="let game of gameslist | orderBy: 'amount'" (click)="GameClick(game.id)">...</tr>
```

my pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: Array<string>, args: string): Array<string> {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if ( a[args] > b[args] ) {
        return -1;
      }else if ( a[args] < b[args] ) {
        return 1;
      }else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

**Before add**
[image: before add]

**after add**
[image: after add]

Comment: Here is a post that discusses pipes and how they work.  This should solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456430/ngfor-doesnt-update-data-with-pipe-in-angular2

Comment: thanks problem solved by adding `pure: false` to the pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by add `pure: false` to the pipe configuration

all thanks to [jmw5598](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3131085/jmw5598)